# Instalação do TensorFlow pelo pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ao tentar instalar o tensorflow pelo pip sempre dá erro, indepentendete de versão do python, pip ou tensorflow.

Ao tentar o comando via cmd:
pip install tensorflow

A resposta é:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: qual o output se você digita `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)` ?

Comment: Antes de instalar o TensorFlow entre neste [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install?hl=pt-br) e leia as informações.

Answer (score 1):

O Tensorflow só funciona com o Python de 64bits entre as versões 3.5 e 3.8.

Você pode verificar a versão do seu python no terminal digitando `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)`

Caso o seu sistema satisfaça as condições acima, verifique se você está com o pip atualizado: `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Você pode tentar instalar o pacote com o link direto para a sua versão do python seguindo essa [lista](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location)

As instruções detalhadas para a instalação do tensorflow com o pip estão [aqui](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)